# Is there something similar to journal for read operations in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am currently developing a program that read documents from mongo and write them in a file... something like this:

```
for doc in db.col.find(field=="bla"):
  file.write(doc)
```

My problem is that something can happen while doing this process (its gonna take a week to do all the writes), for example, a shutdown or network problem. My question is: Is there something similar to journal for write operations to recover from a checkpoint? So I don't need to do all the write to file all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this program will do what you want it writes IDs to a seperate log file. If everything runs fine it will just work. If it fails then the lopfile will ensure you start after the last write. Will also work if the dataset is changing as long as only inserts are done.

It needs Python 3.6 or better for the fStrings and `pymongo`.

```
import pymongo
import  bson.json_util
import pathlib
import os

log_file = "logfile.txt"
output_file = "zip_codes.json"
host = "mongodb+srv://readonly:readonly@demodata.rgl39.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
log_set = frozenset()

# Do we have a log file of previous writes
if os.path.isfile(log_file):
    with open(log_file, "r") as input:
        log_set = frozenset([x.strip() for x in input.readlines()])
        print(f"{log_file} contains {len(log_set)} items")
else: # lets create one that is empty
    pathlib.Path(log_file).touch()
    print(f"creating {log_file}")

# connect to MongoDB we are using a readonly dataset for testing. 
client = pymongo.MongoClient(host)
db = client["demo"]
zipcodes=db["zipcodes"]

count = 0
# Note we use bson to dump the file rather than json.dumps. This ensures
# that we can read this file back into MongoDB.
with open(output_file, "w") as data_output:
    with open(log_file, "w") as log_output:
        for doc in zipcodes.find():
            if doc["_id"] not in log_set: # did we write this record already
                count = count + 1
                data_output.write(f"{bson.json_util.dumps(doc)}\n")
                log_output.write(f"{doc['_id']}\n")
                print(f"inserted {count} docs")
```